# JavaFX enormous lag with larger Canvas dimensions

Tags: java, performance, canvas, javafx

This is kind of a vague question, but I'm trying to create a code editor using JavaFX Canvas technologies and its being incredibly slow for what I'd like.

Take the following code for example

```
public class JavaFXApplication13 extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        int extent = 6300;
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
        Canvas cvs = new Canvas(extent,extent);
        ScrollPane scpn = new ScrollPane();
        root.setTop(cvs);
        scpn.setContent(root);

        root.autosize();
        scpn.autosize();
        GraphicsContext ctx = cvs.getGraphicsContext2D();
        for(int i = 0; extent / 300 > i; i++){
            ctx.setFill(Color.RED);
            ctx.fillRect(i*300, 0, 100, extent);
            ctx.setFill(Color.BLUE);
            ctx.fillRect(i*300+100, 0, 100, extent);
            ctx.setFill(Color.GREEN);
            ctx.fillRect(i*300+200, 0, 100, extent);
        }
////        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(scpn, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

If you try to slide pane around, theres a good few seconds between when you move the cursor and when the scrollbar and the scroll pane update. This has to do with the size of the canvas, which is set to 6300, which is nothing. I can open NotePad and get line heights in the million and its able to draw them with ease.

Performance is even worse when trying to draw on a large sized canvas, simple

```
 onKeyPress((a) -> drawText(a.getText(), ...));
```

takes seconds to process.

I guess what I'm trying to say is, is this performance normal? or should I just suck it up and move on to something more powerful such as OpenGL?

Comment: java -version is 1.8.0_05

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A code editor should be virtual and only draw the lines you see on screen! So IMHO your use of canvas is completely incorrect!

Canvas at its heart can be seen like a buffered image you can draw on and on the OpenGL / Directx side only sees a image.

Why reinvent the wheel there are at least 2 opensource javafx code editors. See https://tomasmikula.github.io/blog/ and http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2014/08/11/efxclipse-1-0-new-features-styledtext-control-to-build-a-code-editor-framework/

Comment: The essentials of the question was never answered, why JScrollPane lags when dealing with high resolution items, but it seems the tool is just meh. Hmph, that just seems silly. I had someone teach me the basics of the JavaScript Canvas and I thought that the principles could be transferred, but it seems I'm wrong. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 3):

I tested JavaFX for a game project about 6 months ago, I was drawing 10000 rectangles and using an animation timer to change the color of each rectangle 60 times a second.

I found that using the canvas for this was really slow and was getting about a frame a second. I changed to just using the scene graph by just adding JavaFX rectangle nodes to a Group node and it worked with no lag.

I was surprised that using JavaFX objects was way more efficient that using the canvas, I am now working on my second JavaFX 2 game using nodes in the scene graph.

Comment: Zyion, FYI I saw this type of performance as well regarding Canvas objects in JavaFX prior to 8u20 however the memory allocation and rendering loops for the Canvas object were fixed with the 8u20 release and are now quite performant. I'm able to render close to a million individually colored ovals across multiple Canvas objects in single digit milliseconds.  Initial load for the Canvas objects is in the 100 ms range.